# eslint: Parsing error: Unexpected character '#', in .scss

Tags: eslint

This is a scss file, Why does this happen?

eslint tips:

> Parsing error: Unexpected character '#'

[image]

Comment: are you sure that it is in the `.scss` file ?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw, if you look at the location of the file in the screenshot, you can see that it is inside the `sidebar.scss` file.

Comment: You can try this `"scss.validate": false,` in the settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because eslint is trying to lint a SCSS file.

You need to exclude SCSS type files. Edit your `package.json` like below:

```js
{
  ...
  "eslintIgnore" : ["**/*.scss"],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can enables or disables all scss validations in the settings like so:

```
"scss.validate": false
```

[Customizing CSS, SCSS and Less Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css)